# IIS 6.0 : Email wasn't receive outside my domain

Tags: c#, email, iis

I have developed a solution that will automatically sent an email upon raising a web form request. However, we have scenarios that the solution will send outside the domain. 
e.g receiver@ymail.com, receiver@gmail.com.

The problem is, the receivers outside the domain didn't received the email.
Also, in the subject line, there is always a prefix saying

```
"UNVERIFIED SENDER: **email subject**"
```

If anybody can help me on how the email receiver outside the domain can received
the email.

I have this configuration on the Web.Config

```
<!--<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="senderemail@mydomain.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.***.*****.com" userName="Username" password="password"  enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>-->
```

This is my c# code for sending email

```
MailMessage objMl = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient objCl = new SmtpClient();
MailAddress mlAdr = new MailAddress(*Receiver's email*);
objMl.To.Add(mlAdr);
objMl.Subject = *Subject*;
objMl.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
objCl.Send(objMl);
```

And this is the IIS SMTP Configuration
[IIS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUGSh.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean that it wasn't received at all, or that it went to the spam folder? How are you sending the e-mail? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Hi John, i have edited my question, I've included my configuration on the web.config. And yes, it wasn't received at all, it also doesn't go to the spam folder.

Comment: So you're using `SmtpClient`? If it works for e-mail addresses @yourdomain.com but not external ones, then it doesn't sound like a code issue at all. You might want to check your mail server configuration.

Comment: Is the mail configuration be in the IIS?

Comment: Well, it looks like you're using `SmtpClient`, so you're using an actual SMTP mail server. The configuration will be on the machine running at `smtp.***.*****.com`.

Comment: If the configuration is exactly like that then it means it’s commented out and not used.

Comment: @Sami Oh, that's a point, I didn't notice it was commented out. jessa Can you show us the C# code that you're using to send the e-mail?

Comment: I believe your SMTP server could be having rules to block mail delivery outside your organisation domain. Check SMTP server logs or ask for help from network admin.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to include the source code and iis configuration

Comment: @jessa You're aware that if users in your domain are receiving e-mails without problems then your code for sending e-mails is fine, right? Your code is doing what it needs to: it's getting e-mails _to the SMTP server_. What happens after that is _dependent on the SMTP server_.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found out the resolution for the concern.

The web server wasn't able to relay outside, so then our server admin add the web server IP address to relay.

Thanks for all the suggestions and answers. :)